# WPF - Attached property needs to reference another bound attached property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, attached-properties

I have created an attached property to set the visibility of a UIElement based on a particular enum value. This works fine. However, I need to extend this so that the visibility can be overriden based on the "status" of the sender.

How can I achieve this? I had thought that I could create another attached property which the first attached property could reference, however I need to be able to bind a value to the second attached property rather than just set to an enum value.

**EDIT**

Below is an example of my problem:

```
<Window x:Class="AttachedProperty.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:attachedProperty="clr-namespace:AttachedProperty"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Button should be enabled?"/>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CanClick}"/>
        <Button Content="Click Me" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanClick}"/>
        <Button Content="Manager Only Click" attachedProperty:SecurityBehavior.IsEnabledRole="Mgr"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The first button's enabled property is just controlled using the checkbox.
The second button's enabled property is controlled by an attachedProperty that determines if you are in the correct security group:

```
    public class SecurityBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledRoleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsEnabledRole", typeof (string), typeof (SecurityBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnIsEnabledRoleChanged));

    private static void OnIsEnabledRoleChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // In here have some logic that determines if the current user is authorised
        // Principal.IsInRole(e.NewValue.ToString() ? true : false;
        sender.SetValue(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty, true);
    }

    public static void SetIsEnabledRole(DependencyObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsEnabledRoleProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetIsEnabledRole(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (string) element.GetValue(IsEnabledRoleProperty);
    }
}
```

When run both buttons are enabled - the 1st because the checkbox is checked and the second because I am a manager. When I uncheck the checkbox the 1st button is disabled and I want my attached property to be able to only enable if in the correct security group **AND** the checkbox is checked.

How can I change by sample so that I can get have the behavior that sets the IsEnabled based on 2 possible inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're after attached properties for this. Based on your requirement you could pull this off with a simple `IValueConverter` and a `Binding` for the `Visibility` of the final control.

So say we have an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  StateOne,
  StateTwo
}
```

and a `CheckBox` such as:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkBox"
          Content="Check Me!!!" />
```

Now if we want some `Button`'s `Visibility` to only be visible when enum is `StateOne` and the checkbox is checked,

we could just have a converter such as:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    var checkBoxIsChecked = (bool)value;
    var givenEnum = (MyEnum)parameter;
    return checkBoxIsChecked && givenEnum == MyEnum.StateOne ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

and in xaml for the `Button`'s:

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox"
            Content="Check Me!!!" />

  <Button Content="Button One"
          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=chkBox,
                                Path=IsChecked,
                                Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},
                                ConverterParameter={x:Static local:MyEnum.StateOne}}" />

  <Button Content="Button Two"
          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=chkBox,
                                Path=IsChecked,
                                Converter={StaticResource MyConverter},
                                ConverterParameter={x:Static local:MyEnum.StateTwo}}" />

</StackPanel>
```

With this, "Button One" will become visible when the checkbox is checked, however button two will not as the `ConverterParameter` passed in for button two is `StateTwo`.

If it's the `IsEnabled` state you want to control of the `Button`, just switch the binding to that property and in the converter just return true or false accordingly instead of `Visibility.Visible`

Even if you choose to provide the enum value not static and dynamic, you could just make the  `Binding` a `MultiBinding` and switch the `IValueConverter` to an `IMultiValueConverter`

**Update:**

If for whatever reason you have to go down the route of attached properties, then in the property changed callback of each attached property get the other properties value from the sender and perform your logic accordingly.

```
public class SecurityBehavior {
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledRoleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsEnabledRole",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(SecurityBehavior),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(OnIsEnabledRoleChanged));

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabled2RoleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsEnabled2Role",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(SecurityBehavior),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(OnIsEnabled2RoleChanged));

  private static void OnIsEnabledRoleChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    HandleAttachedPropertyUpdate(sender, (string)e.NewValue, GetIsEnabled2Role(sender));
  }

  private static void OnIsEnabled2RoleChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    HandleAttachedPropertyUpdate(sender, GetIsEnabledRole(sender), (bool)e.NewValue);
  }

  private static void HandleAttachedPropertyUpdate(DependencyObject sender, string isEnabledRole, bool isEnabled2Role) {
    sender.SetValue(UIElement.IsEnabledProperty, isEnabledRole == "Mgr" && isEnabled2Role);
  }

  public static void SetIsEnabledRole(DependencyObject element, string value) {
    element.SetValue(IsEnabledRoleProperty, value);
  }

  public static string GetIsEnabledRole(DependencyObject element) {
    return (string)element.GetValue(IsEnabledRoleProperty);
  }

  public static void SetIsEnabled2Role(DependencyObject element, bool value) {
    element.SetValue(IsEnabled2RoleProperty, value);
  }

  public static bool GetIsEnabled2Role(DependencyObject element) {
    return (bool)element.GetValue(IsEnabled2RoleProperty);
  }
}
```

and xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
  <CheckBox x:Name="chkBox"
            Content="Check Me!!!" />
  <Button Content="Button One"
          local:SecurityBehavior.IsEnabled2Role="{Binding ElementName=chkBox,
                                                          Path=IsChecked}"
          local:SecurityBehavior.IsEnabledRole="Mgr" />
  <Button Content="Button Two"
          local:SecurityBehavior.IsEnabled2Role="{Binding ElementName=chkBox,
                                                          Path=IsChecked}"
          local:SecurityBehavior.IsEnabledRole="NotMgr" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I could use a converter as you suggest but there will be many different places where this will be needed and although a converter would work I thought that it would make the XAML cleaner if the functionality could be wrapped in an attached property/attached behavior

Comment: I don't know I prefer to keep as much UI related stuff in xaml where possible. You can always define a base `Style` and assign the property there if you wanted to reduce replication or have a Custom DP to hold the enum value if you wanted to bring it down even further. Just not attracted to attached properties for these stuff. That's why we got Binding's and MultiBinding's and converters in the first place :)

Comment: @DavidWard I've edited my answer and given you the answer you were looking for with attached properties. Do consider the other option too though :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer what I've asked for whilst also pointing out why I was trying to do the wrong thing. I was blindly heading the way of attached properties and yet the answer was a lot simpler with multi binding converter all along...thanks